# Merge multiple rows to single row - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe which contains 8 rows of dict values. I wanted to merge all rows to single row with comma. Since my dataframe contains dict values I am getting a error. Is that possible to merge dict values to one row?

I have a dataframe like below,

```
         names                              names1
0        {'name':'Ashwin'}       {'name':'prem'}
1        {'name':'Alex'}         {'name':'Naga'}
```

I wanted it to be,
       names                                                 names
0  {'name':'Ashwin'},{'name':'Alex'}         {'name':'prem'},{'name':'Naga'}

Please Note : dtype should not change from dict

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is `names` column `str` or `dict` valued

Comment: @QuangHoang - columns type is str

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert column to list and call `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'names': [df['names'].tolist()]})
print (df)
                                               names
0  [{'name': 'Ashwin', 'age': '26'}, {'name': 'Al...
```

If values are strings and need list of dictionaries:

```
import ast

df = pd.DataFrame({'names': [df['names'].apply(ast.literal_eval).tolist()]})
print (df)
                                               names
0  [{'name': 'Ashwin', 'age': '26'}, {'name': 'Al...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
df_new=df.apply(','.join).reset_index(drop=True).rename('name')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you only want a string value, you can use `''.join()` as an aggregate function:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.agg(lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str)))).T
```

it gives:

```
                                               names
0  {'name': 'Ashwin', 'age': '26'},{'name': 'Alex...
```